# Scaling or triming lines (stroke) on javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the transparent canvas (200x200). And the object drawed line by line on this canvas using solid stroke (lineTo method). I need to make this object full-width before or after **ctx.stroke();**.

[image: Image for example]

Answer (score 1):

**You can scale your drawing to the full canvas width like this:**

- Save all your moveTo & lineTo coordinates in an array.
- Find the max and min X coordinate values.
- Calculate the width of the drawing: `var drawingWidth = maxX - minX`.
- Shift the drawing to the left edge of the canvas by subtracting minX from every X coordinate in the array.
- Calculate the required factor to scale the drawing to the full width of the canvas: `var scale = canvas.width / drawingWidth`.
- Tell the canvas to scale to the desired factor: `context.scale(scale,scale)`
- Clear the canvas and redraw all the saved coordinates.
- Clean up by unscaling the canvas: `context.scale(-scale,-scale)`